# Pandas: Combining dataframes with same column names but different calculations

Tags: python, pandas

I have a two dataframes for active and inactive customers. Both the active and inactive dataframes have the same columns but the experience_duration is calculated differently.

Sample data active:

```
ID| join_date | experience_duration| status

 1| 2013-12-05|               4.321| active

 2| 2013-12-05|               4.321| active
```

Sample data inactive:

```
ID| join_date | experience_duration| status

 5| 2013-12-05|                  14| inactive

 9| 2013-12-05|                  52| inactive
```

I want to merge this to the master customer data frame which has various customer attributes. It should look like:

```
ID| join_date  | gender| experience_duration| status

 1| 2013-12-05 |      F|               4.321| active

 2| 2013-12-05 |      M|               4.321| active

 5| 2013-12-05 |      F|                  14| inactive

 9| 2013-12-05 |      F|                  52| inactive
```

Code:

```
df_customer = pd.merge(left=df_customer, right=df_active, on=['id'], 
how='left')
df_customer = pd.merge(left=df_customer, right=df_inactive, on=['id'], 
how='left')
```

The problem is that I end up with duplicate columns for experience duration. I want one experience duration column with the appropriate values based on the status of the customer.

Comment: It looks like you might want to concatenate the df's instead of merging them. Is it possible for a single user to be in both df's?

Comment: No the user is either inactive or active. However they might exist already in the final df and I just want to add this column

Comment: oh I see, so there are actually 3 df's. That wasn't clear to me first reading the question. Does the `experience_duration` column already exist in the `df_customer`?

You've shown one merge above, but you're really doing a second merge with `df_customer` and `df_inactive` afterwards right?

Could you edit your question to make this more clear?

Comment: the experience_duration does not exist in the df_customer. I calculate it separately for inactive and active.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
final_df = pd.concat([activeDf, inactiveDf])
```

You can also do:

```
final_df = activeDf.append(inactiveDf)
```

---

Read more here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html